# Stick deodorant through airport security

Tags: air-travel, airports, airport-security

Do you have to put stick deodorant in your quart size bag in your carry on or gallon bag in your checked or would I be allowed to just leave it in with my clothes?
Btw I am going to Philadelphia then Mexico if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2):

A quick google search returns this TSA page:

"Stick deodorant [is fine](https://www.tsa.gov/blog/2013/07/09/tsa-travel-tips-tuesday-flying-deodorant-isnt-sticky-situation) in any size. Well, almost any size… Powders and crystals are good to go as well"

For fun, click on the link on the tsa page (under "almost any size").

Comment: That is the kind of stick deodorant that is not liquid or cream.

Answer (score 0):

It's specifically allowed by the TSA but that doesn't mean it doesn't get flagged by a security agent that's having a bad day or is just not good at their job.

I recently got yelled at for bringing having deo stick and not putting it in the quart bag. Although a deo stick is specifically allowed, trying to argue the point with the officer is counterproductive, especially if you still want to make your flight.